# Dos formas del subjuntivo imperfecto ("-ra" y "-se") que fueron usadas en una oración por una misma persona

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

Simpre creía que cada persona normalmente usa solo una de los dos formas del subjuntivo imperfecto como una preferencía personal. Pero encontré algunos ejemplos que muestran lo contrario:

Del libro "El arte de no amargarse la vida" (España):

*"A partir de entonces, se fueron sucediendo situaciones de ansiedad en las que tenía que salir corriendo estuvie**ra** donde estuvie**se**.."*

Un ejemplo más de "El arte de no amargarse la vida":

"*Y así empecé a aceptar con actitud positiva todo aquello que no podía cambiar. Fue**ra** lo que fue**se**.*"

De la serie de Netflix "La Víctima Número Ocho" (España):

"¿*Era mucho pedir que espera**ses** a que le incinerá**ramos** para anunciarlo*?"

De un video de DW (en 0:26) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8Tz4YgsIxA (no estoy seguro de que esta transcripción sea completamente correcta en todas las palabras):

"*El presidente me dijo en más de una vez que quería tener a una persona de contacto, alguien a quien pudie**ra** llamar que lo pudie**se** contactar y pasar las informaciones y reportes de inteligencia*".

Preguntas:

1. ¿Por qué una misma persona usa ambas formas del subjuntivo imperfecto en una oración?
2. ¿Sería el mismo significado si en todos los ejemplos arriba usáramos ambos verbos en la misma forma ("*-se*" y "*-se*" o "*-ra*" y "*-ra*")?
3. ¿Se puede usar ambas formas en el tercer condicional como en "*Si hubie**ses** estado allí me hubie**ra** muerto de miedo*"? Este ejemplo yo construí por mi cuenta.

P.S. Como siempre, les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores si hay algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Las construcciones:

- Fuera lo que fuese / Fuera como fuese ...
- Estuviera donde estuviese ...

son prácticamente frases hechas donde se aprovecha la alternancia (y equivalencia) de las dos formas del pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo para evitar la repetición cacofónica de la misma forma, que gramaticalmente también sería correcta:

- Fuera lo que fuera / Fuera como fuera ...
- Estuviera donde estuviera ...

Del mismo modo, en las oraciones:

- ¿Era mucho pedir que esperases a que le incineráramos para anunciarlo?
- El presidente me dijo en más de una vez que quería tener a una persona de contacto, alguien a quien pudiera llamar, que lo pudiese contactar y pasar las informaciones y reportes de inteligencia.

podría haberse usado la misma forma en ambos verbos. Es sólo una cuestión de preferencia o de estilo:

- ¿Era mucho pedir que esperases a que le incinerásemos para anunciarlo?
- El presidente me dijo en más de una vez que quería tener a una persona de contacto, alguien a quien pudiera llamar, que lo pudiera contactar y pasar las informaciones y reportes de inteligencia.

Con respecto a la pregunta sobre la alternancia entre el pluscuamperfecto del subjuntivo y el condicional perfecto en la apódosis de las oraciones condicionales, ambas formas son correctas y, según [esta página](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Condicional%20hipot%C3%A9tico.htm), es cuestión de preferencia:

> En cuanto a la alternancia en las oraciones condicionales, según la RAE "tiene pleno uso decir: *Si hubiese hecho buen tiempo hubiera salido* (junto a habría salido)."
>
> El Libro de Estilo de El País da, sin embargo, preferencia al condicional compuesto en estos casos: "En estos casos de relación con subjuntivo, es preferible siempre la forma potencial en los tiempos compuestos. No se debe escribir: S*i hubieras pedido que lo hiciera, yo lo hubiese hecho*. Es más correcto: *Si hubieras pedido que lo hiciera, yo lo habría hecho*."

Comment: He entendido en general. ¿Podrías aclarar también sobre los ejemplos de "La Víctima Número Ocho" y DW? ¿También ambas formas se usaron solo para evitar la repetición cacofónica?

Comment: Agregado a la respuesta. Aplica lo mismo que expliquè al principio.